# Easy to learn, freeware PHP content management for small website with user associated data

Tags: gratis, php, framework

I am building a small to medium sized website for a potential business.

In the first phase, I would like the site to have the following features:

- Users with login/passwords. The users will have data associated with their accounts.
- Page flows, many of which will appear similar to each other.
- Quick response time.
- Running on freeware.
- The coding framework should not have too large of a learning curve (I do not have any PHP experience with a framework).

In the second phase:

- "Manager" accounts, whereby the managers can see the data relating to individual users.

If not too difficult, I would the ability for administrators to be able to publish content without editing any back-end code. However, this is optional and should not come at the expense of any other requirements.

I am able to use PHP 5.5+, preferably for Unix.

Comment: Maybe https://bolt.cm/ is a good solution for you. It supports Twig templates and is PHP based.

Answer (score 1):

Using WordPress simply as backend content management is an option and I think it matches all your conditions to the first and second phase. I know of three ways of using WordPress in the frontend without using WP to display the content:

1. [Add a couple of lines](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59308/12615) to your PHP files and use WordPress functions to pull content:

   ```
   <?php
   define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
   require( './wp-load.php' );
   // WordPress functions are available here
   ```
2. Install a plugin like [JSON REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) and pull the data into any kind of app (mobile, desktop, web).
3. Use [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) to add/delete/retrieve data (not sure about mobile).

Maybe some Micro-CMS could do the same job, but can't recommend anything. Worth noting that WP admin can be heavily reduced and customised.

Comment: I will have to do some more research before I mark your answer as accept, but this certainly looks like a good place to start. Thanks!

Comment: @pat, updated answer, you can research for Micro-CMS as well, looking for a way to do 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Drupal with Views module. It has an out-of-the-box support for user profiles, custom content types with own properties, roles and permissions. It has plenty of modules too and it is very fast with caching enabled.

Comment: You probably should have mentioned Rules, LoginTobogin, Panels and DisplaySuite as well.